# Wordpress shows a blank white page during installation

Tags: mysql, wordpress, apache

I am trying to make a WordPress installation on Ubuntu 20.04. I have the LAMP(Linux, Apache, MySQL & PHP) stack installed but I don't understand why when i load the localhost folder, asin `localhost/wordpress`,the result is just a white background. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution. The problem was that I forgot to install PHP while setting up my LAMP stack.
So I just run:
`sudo apt install php libapache2-mod-php php-mysql` to install PHP and other needed modules.
To check PHP version installed, run:
`php -v`

Answer (score 0):

Clean your cache and increase PHP memory limit to aleast 96MB-128MB